# Scrolling of a listbox inside another listbox

Tags: wpf, layout, listbox

I have a listbox (with normal vertical orientation), each element of which is a listbox with **horizontal** orientation.
I want to have a ScrollBar inside of **internal** listbox. So, my problem is how to set width of internal listbox according to real current width of external.

My current code is:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="ItemTemplateSchedule">
        <ListBox>
            <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ListBoxItem>My-Very-Long-Item-Nimber-1___</ListBoxItem>
            <ListBoxItem>My-Very-Long-Item-Nimber-2___</ListBoxItem>
            <ListBoxItem>My-Very-Long-Item-Nimber-3___</ListBoxItem>
            <ListBoxItem>My-Very-Long-Item-Nimber-4___</ListBoxItem>
            <ListBoxItem>My-Very-Long-Item-Nimber-5___</ListBoxItem>
        </ListBox>
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>

<Grid>
    <ListBox ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ItemTemplateSchedule}" >
        >
    </ListBox>
</Grid>
```

Current screenshot:
[image: Listbox inside listbox]
.

**UPD1**

Ok, answer to my question is setting of width for internal listbox, thanks to **@sa_ddam213**:

```
Width="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=ListBox}, Path=ActualWidth}"
```

Now I want add some new control in each row of external listbox:

```
<HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="ItemTemplateSchedule">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Width="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=ListBox}, Path=ActualWidth}">
        <TextBlock Text="This is Text in a TextBlock"/>
        <ListBox >
            <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ListBoxItem>My-Very-Long-Item-Number-1___</ListBoxItem>
            <ListBoxItem>My-Very-Long-Item-Number-2___</ListBoxItem>
            <ListBoxItem>My-Very-Long-Item-Number-3___</ListBoxItem>
            <ListBoxItem>My-Very-Long-Item-Number-4___</ListBoxItem>
            <ListBoxItem>My-Very-Long-Item-Number-5___</ListBoxItem>
        </ListBox>
    </StackPanel>
</HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```

And it doesn't work now! Is it possible to solve this problem? Current screenshot:
[image: upd1]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `FindAncestor` to bind to the parent `ListBox` `ActualWidth`

Example:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="ItemTemplateSchedule">
        <ListBox Width="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=ListBox}, Path=ActualWidth}" >
            <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ListBoxItem>My-Very-Long-Item-Nimber-1___</ListBoxItem>
            <ListBoxItem>My-Very-Long-Item-Nimber-2___</ListBoxItem>
            <ListBoxItem>My-Very-Long-Item-Nimber-3___</ListBoxItem>
            <ListBoxItem>My-Very-Long-Item-Nimber-4___</ListBoxItem>
            <ListBoxItem>My-Very-Long-Item-Nimber-5___</ListBoxItem>
        </ListBox>
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you! It works fine. But if I want insert some new control into each row of external layout, it doesn't work. See UPD1 in my post.